# Firefox and IE cherrypicking from CSS stylesheet, works in Chrome

Tags: html, css

My site [rrrepo](https://rrrepo.co) renders fine in Chrome, but is crazy in FF and IE.

Here's a couple examples of repos, https://rrrepo.co/repo/SublimeText
https://rrrepo.co/repo/Marketing

There are different themes for the repos, and we apply a separate css file for those colors, ie red.css = header {background:red} and blue.css = header {background:blue}.

On the repos above, you can see that the they both pull the correct color for the main section (the middle part), but do not pull in the correct background colors for the left and right hand sidebars. I know it's picking up the specific color css file, as the middle section is grabbing the color from it.

It works fine in Chrome, but is completely broken in FF and IE. They seem to just cherrypick which things to listen to from the CSS file. It's very strange and I have no idea how to solve it.

Any help would be SO appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Repo in Edge. We need more information, perhaps edit your question to show us a bit of your CSS?

Comment: From the look of the console, the font-face for `gotham-medium.eot` appears to be throwing an error in IE. Can you comment out the use of that font for a test run? Also, side note, you are outputting comments via `console.log()` - not good if the site is live